# C++ Error clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, file, header-files, code-splitting

I am a beginner in C++, I encountered a big problem when learning, I don't know if it is a problem with my editor or my computer, there is always an error, I look for a lot of answers, just can't solve it, please help me, thank you very much

I'm using Monterey version 12.6, the MacOS operating system

I use VSCode as my development tool
My tool has extensions for C++
Here is my code:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "swap.h"

int main()
{

  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;
  swap(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

// swap.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int a, int b);
```

// swap.cpp

```
#include "swap.h"

void swap(int a, int b)
{
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;

  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;
}
```

**When I run this program, there is an error in the console**
*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"swap(int, int)", referenced from:
_main in main-7515ff.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

Attached is my screenshot：

[image]

[image]

I searched for a lot of answers, and it took me a long time, but I still couldn't get the answer. Please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Specify `swap.cpp` on the command line.

Comment: Some pointers regarding things that aren’t related to your current problem, but may cause you things in the future: 1. If you want to use `using namespace std;`, do it _after_ any `#include`s, otherwise it can lead to some very interesting bugs. When coming across link/compile errors, always include how you’re building your code in your question. And finally, even though compilers and what not aren’t flawless, they’re used by millions of people every day. 99.99% of the time, if there’s an issue, it’s something the programmer is doing wrong, not the compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reminder I solved this problem and it is already working. :)

Answer (score 1):

What that error means is that `g++` sees that you are referencing a function named `swap` that takes 2 int parameters, but it doesn’t see a *definition* of that function in any of the files you gave it.

You need to add `swap.cpp` to the sources list, g++ doesn’t know that you want to include this file automatically (it sees that you want `swap.h`, but the fact that they’re related is just a matter of convention; Not something a compiler can know about on its own without you telling it):

```bash
g++ main.cpp swap.cpp -o main
```

Or alternatively (a bit wordier, but this is closer to how build tools typically do it, which you’ll come across soon in your learning):

```bash
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c swap.cpp -o swap.o
g++ main.o swap.o -o main
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reminder I solved this problem and it is already working